# how to pass a params into a controller action in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters

i would appreciate if someone could help me on ruby on rails.
can i pass a params[:something] onto a controller?

in my index view i have

```
       <button value="1" name="most_recent" type="submit" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Most Recent</button>
       <button value="1" name="score" type="submit" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Score</button>
```

essentially if a button is pressed, the value goes into my index controller and i can receive it by doing

```
 params[:score]
```

to see if the score button was pressed. however, also on my index template i have

```
     <%= form_tag search_photos_path, :method => 'get' do %>
        <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], 
                :class => "input-medium search-query expand" %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Search', :name => nil, :class => "btn" %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
```

when a user clicks search, it goes to my search action. is there a way to send what params[:score] is? if it has been clicked, i want to be able to know it has been clicked. i tried doing params[:search] in my search action, but it returns nil even though i clicked on the search button.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add hidden input field within a form inside your template with the value of

```
params[:score]
```

Comment: how do you do that exactly? i tried doing it and i keep getting nil still

Comment: i got it. i had to do <%= %>. i wonder why i had to add the equals sign. cause its not like im printing out anything to the screen.

Comment: <%= %> by itself doesn't print anything to the screen, it adds the evaluated result to the markup. Since hidden field is not visible, you cannot see it.